# how to use N with "insert into" command which have "?" as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

it's normally that to use N like below.

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
       ([FieldID]
       ,[Description])
 VALUES
       (1000,N'test'),(1001,N'test2')
```

but how to implement N in commend like

```
INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]
       ([FieldID]
       ,[Description])
 VALUES
       (?,?),(?,?)
```

Comment: Use proper parameters instead of these hokey `?`s?

Comment: What framework are you using? `N` just tells that you are passing Unicode.

Comment: The question seems to be solely about SQLServer and nothing to do with Java/JDBC (based on the approved answer); the tags should be adjusted accordingly?

Comment: @MickMnemonic - I was wondering that, too. The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39878022/revisions) shows that the question was originally about T-SQL and then was completely changed to a JDBC/CallableStatement question. My Stack-fu is insufficient to determine whether or not the question edit happened *after* the answer was accepted, but at this point I'm prepared to just walk away from the whole mess.

Comment: ( cc: @MickMnemonic ) I have rolled back the question edit so the question matches the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not use `?` for parameters, this is something that you usually find in Ole data sources (see [OLE DB Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141696.aspx)), they are usually also position specific (ordinal).

For SQL Server use names prefixed with `@` as parameters. These are always named and the names should be unique. Each parameter must also be of a specific type. For parameters that contain Unicode text use the SQL Server type `NVarChar` (`N'text'` usually indicates `NVarChar`) and also specify the appropriate length. As the parameters are named defining the parameter and the position(s) the parameter occupies in a statement are not related in that the 2nd defined parameter could be used before the first defined parameter in a statement.

Your example refactored:

```
-- define your parameters
DECLARE @p1 INT, @p3 INT
DECLARE @p2 nvarchar(1000), @p4 nvarchar(1000)

-- set your parameter values (note: this could be done on the same line as the declaration)
SET @p1 = 1
SET @p2 = N'some text'
-- etc.

INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] ([FieldID], [Description])
VALUES (@p1, @p2), (@p3, @p4)
```

See also

- [MSDN - Specify Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260.aspx)
- [Using Variables and Parameters (Database Engine)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175852(v=sql.105).aspx)